# Ajax Request return : data Udefined After Success

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, web

I am trying to do some Get_Data from dataBase Using asynchronous `ajax` request and `WebMethod`  
Everything works fine , but when i want the returned value from my web method value , i got undefined value

**I Know That this question is asked before**
I have tried almost all advices to achieve my wanted goal , but unfortunately nothing happened .

1. Create Instance Outside the function than set it to the return value.
2. Set The `dataType:"Json"`
3. Create an instance inside the function and set it to empty string 
    `var ReturnValue="";`
4. Let Json object stringify my returned value

and many other steps

**So please do not mark my question as duplicated value**

Here is my code below :

```
//Javascript and Jquery Codes
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#PValidateLogin").hide();

 });

 function killSpaces(element) {
     var characters = element.toString();
     var resultText = "";
     for (var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
         if (!(characters[i] == " ")) {
             resultText += characters[i];
         }
     }
     return resultText;
 }


 $("#<%=btnLogin.ClientID%>").click(function() {
     var MyWantedhref;
     var Result = ValidateMyLogin();
     if (typeof Result === "undefined") {
         alert("Something wrong with codes");
     } else if (Result == "false" || killSpaces(Result).length == 0) {
         alert("wrong user ");
     } else {
         MyWantedhref = "/Frm_Manager/frm_MenuCategory.aspx";
         location.replace(MyWantedhref);
     }
 });


 function ValidateMyLogin() {
     var ReturValue;
     var UserName = $("#<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>").val();
     var Password = $("#<%=txtUserPassword.ClientID%>").val();
     if (killSpaces(Password).length >= 4 && killSpaces(UserName).length >= 4) {
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             url: "frm_ValidateLogin.aspx/ValidateLogin",
             data: "{'UserName':'" + UserName + "','Password':'" + Password + "'}",
             success: function(data) {
                 ReturValue = data.d;
             },
             error: function(err) {
                 ReturValue = err.d;
             }
         });
     }

     return ReturValue;
 }
```

**And Here are the C# Code**

```
<code>
 private static OwnerAccountBO _OwnerAccountBO;
        public static OwnerAccountBO OwnerAccountBO { get { return new OwnerAccountBO(); } set { _OwnerAccountBO = value; } }

        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public static string ValidateLogin(string UserName, string Password)
        {
            string CharResult = "";
            object[] UserParameters = { UserName, Password };
            int Result = OwnerAccountBO.validateLogin(UserParameters);
            if (Result > 0)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["OwnerAccountID"] = Result;
                CharResult += Convert.ToString(Result);
            }
            else
            {
                CharResult += "false";
            }
            return CharResult;
        }
</code>
```

Please Any Help would be thankful . 
And of course i want a proper explication for the wrong action or flow that i am doing to have such error

Comment: How you know that 'undefined' is there from 'success' Method

Comment: i so know because i set a breakpoint in c# to the returned value , and it returns my wanted value ,Hence on javascript ypu make breakpoint using f12 on javascript and you reload your page , in this way you can debug yourjavascript code

Comment: Bro your success and error methods are doing same so how you will decide which is fired on call

Comment: put alerts in corresponding method and display valid messages there

Answer (score 0):

You returned a string value from the method

```
string CharResult = "";
        object[] UserParameters = { UserName, Password };
        int Result = OwnerAccountBO.validateLogin(UserParameters);
        if (Result > 0)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["OwnerAccountID"] = Result;
            CharResult += Convert.ToString(Result);
        }
        else
        {
            CharResult += "false";
        }
        return CharResult;
```

so in you ajax it must be received like this

```
                      $.ajax({ 
                        success: function (data)
                        {                                
                            ReturValue = data; //fixed it with this
                        }  
                    });
```

Not

```
$.ajax({ success: function (data)
                            {                                
                                ReturValue = data.d; //issue here 
                            },
                            error: function (err)
                            {
                                ReturValue = err.d;
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: Nope this did not helped me : data still undefined

Comment: message
:
"data is not defined"
stack
:
"ReferenceError: data is not defined↵    at eval (eval at ValidateMyLogin (http://localhost:16725/frm_ValidateLogin.aspx:62:17), <anonymous>:1:1)↵    at ValidateMyLogin (http://localhost:16725/frm_ValidateLogin.aspx:111:17)↵    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:16725/frm_ValidateLogin.aspx:71:30)↵    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (http://localhost:16725/cssAndJs/Scripts_All/jquery.min.js:3:10316)↵    at HTMLInputElement.q.handle (http://localhost:16725/cssAndJs/Scripts_All/jquery.min.js:3:8343)"
__proto__
:
Error